# singleton database connection

Tags: python, mysql

I want to retrieve the value from database "details" for that i want to create only one connection with DB, if connection exists don't make a new connection and continue with the previous one. for that i have tried with following:

```
import MySQLdb
import re
import os

class Find:

    def __init__(self,addr):
        self.addr = addr


    dsn = {
    'username': 'xyz',
    'password': 'xyz',
    'hostname': 'localhost',
    'database': 'details'
    }
    the_database_connection = False

    def connect(self,dsn):
        '''This function saves the database connection, so if invoke this again, it gives you the same one, rather than making a second connection.'''
        global the_database_connection
        if not the_database_connection:
            try:
                the_database_connection = MySQLdb.connect(
                    host=dsn['hostname'],
                    user=dsn['username'],
                    passwd=dsn['password'],
                    db=dsn['database'])
            # so modifications take effect automatically
                the_database_connection.autocommit(True)
            except MySQLdb.Error, e:
                print ("Couldn't connect to database. MySQL error %d: %s" %(e.args[0], e.args[1]))
        return the_database_connection
        x=conn.cursor()
        sql = "select * from persons where address = %s" % addr
        x.execute(sql)
        rows = x.fetchall()
        for row in rows:
            print row

if __name__ == "__main__":
    a = Find(addr = "new street")
    a.connect()
```

But this showing error: a.connect takes 2 argument one is define...
how can i define the above dsn.

Comment: You call a.connect without dsn parameter, remove it and use self.dsn

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to reinvent connection pool.

Unfortunately, your solution would not work as is. Using the same connection is only feasible when all connection parameters - host, port, database, username, password are exactly the same. In your case, you return the same connection in any case and this is simply wrong - you must create new connection if any properties are different.

Instead, just use one of existing connection pooling libraries, like [pysqlpool](http://code.google.com/p/pysqlpool/) or [DBUtils](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/DBUtils/) (I am sure there are others).

Comment: i want to connect with the DB only once and access the data. I don't want to hit the Db again so what is the required soluion for that

Comment: If connection parameters are different, you cannot avoid this. If you use connection pooler, it will do that for you automatically without you doing anything

Comment: Parameters are always same

Comment: Actually i got stuck why it is showing this error. Do have any solution for this.

Comment: So you are willing to write a function which is not reusable and is guaranteed to create problems for you or for somebody who is going to use and maintain it after you?

Comment: Do you have any other idea how to create a connection once and get the data. Please share with me

Answer (score 0):

You weren't feeding the a.connect function the dsn information as required. Pull the dsn info out of the class and make it part of the main function. Then feed it back as the argument for a.connect. Like so:

```
import MySQLdb
import re
import os

class Find:

    def __init__(self,addr):
        self.addr = addr

    def connect(self,dsn):
        '''This function saves the database connection, so if invoke this again, it     gives you the same one, rather than making a second connection.'''
        global the_database_connection
        if not the_database_connection:
            try:
                the_database_connection = MySQLdb.connect(
                    host=dsn['hostname'],
                    user=dsn['username'],
                    passwd=dsn['password'],
                    db=dsn['database'])
                # so modifications take effect automatically
                the_database_connection.autocommit(True)
            except MySQLdb.Error, e:
                print ("Couldn't connect to database. MySQL error %d: %s" %(e.args[0], e.args[1]))
        return the_database_connection
        x=conn.cursor()
        sql = "select * from persons where address = %s" % addr
        x.execute(sql)
        rows = x.fetchall()
        for row in rows:
            print row

if __name__ == "__main__":
    a = Find(addr = "new street")
    dsn = {
    'username': 'xyz',
    'password': 'xyz',
    'hostname': 'localhost',
    'database': 'details'
    }
    the_database_connection = False
    a.connect(dsn)
```

Comment: It is showing error: def connect(self,self.dsn): SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Removed my second code snippet. Use the first. If the database connection params will never change then just initialize them at the start of the main function.

Comment: it is working fine... But i have another question: I put print statement1 after the global the_database_connection and another print statement2 at the end of try. when i am executing query 1st time both statement prints but another time only one print statement should print why both are printing? My objective is to establish a connection once and reuse the same connection for further queries.

Comment: So that the limit for number of connection of database will not exceed

Comment: It sounds like your global var the_database_connection isn't working correctly. Instead of making it global, pass it into the connect function as an argument and return it at the end. There isn't a need for it to be global anyway. Also, if my answer fixed your problem, please select it as having answered your question. Thanks.

Comment: when i am executing this query first time it is returning a connection, but on second time it is not using the same connection instead of using the same connection it is creating a new connection.. But i want the same connection every time..Any suggestion for this...